# Differentiation ASPxHiddenField Set and Get method

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I find that Add method and Set method are same function but I don't know what different in this 2 method? Can explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods are mapped to [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) Add and indexer methods. The Add method will throw an exception if the key already exists. Set method will override existing value.

```
ASPxHiddenField hiddenField = new ASPxHiddenField();
hiddenField.Add("key1", "value1");
hiddenField.Set("key1", "value2");  // this will properly set key1 value
hiddenField.Add("key1", "value3");  // this will throw exception
```